# Skip header lines in csv

Tags: json, csv, python-3.7

I am converting csv a file json and am tryng to skip the first 5 header lines
An example file:

```
No errors               
No warnings             
646 ms              
data source=metars              
4797 results                
raw_tex station_id  observation_time    latitude    longitude
stuff   KJES            2019-09-12T22:21:00Z    31.55           -81.88
stuff   KRQB            2019-09-12T22:20:00Z    43.72           -85.5
stuff   LATI            2019-09-12T22:20:00Z    41.42           19.72
stuff   KSTK            2019-09-12T22:20:00Z    40.62           -103.27
```

code:

```
import csv, json

csvFilePath = "metars.csv"
jsonFilePath = 'metars.json'

data = {}
with open(csvFilePath) as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for csvRow in csvReader:
        icao = csvRow['station_id']
        data[icao] = csvRow

with open(jsonFilePath, 'w') as jsonFile:
    jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Errors:
It gives a key error because of the header lines

If I delete the header lines the conversion works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip the lines yourself before creating the reader:

```
with open(csvFilePath) as csvFile:
    for _ in range(5):
        csvFile.readline()
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
```